# Restricting numpy.random.lognormal to a given range, Python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm trying to sample a random number using a log normal distribution fitted to a data set of ages.

```
Age_abscess = numpy.random.lognormal(mean=numpy.log(29.9090909),
              sigma=numpy.log(11.6574484),size=None)
```

I sometimes get answers to the tune of something ^23 and smaller than 1. Given that I want these to be ages, is there a way to restrict the draw to be between 0 and 100?

Edit: After some brainstorming I came up with:

```
def lognormal(mean,sigma):
    age = numpy.random.lognormal(mean=numpy.log(mean),sigma=numpy.log(sigma),size=None)
    if 0>= age <= 100:
    age=age
return age
```

However, this will only run once, so I'll have to figure out how to loop it until it satisfies the condition. This has probably been asked before-will update if I find the answer.

Comment: you have an indentation error in the conditional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for truncated log-normal distribution. Numpy doesn't have one but you can find other custom implementations like [this one](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/py_src/log_normal_truncated_ab/log_normal_truncated_ab.html):

The other option that you have is to discard your drawing and repeat it if your condition of age is not met!

Edit: if you want to drop the values you don't want you'll just need to replace the for with while in your code:

Edit 2: as kevinkayaks pointed out, you'll need to create an infinite loop and break once your condition is met!

```
def lognormal(mean,sigma):
    while True:
        age = numpy.random.lognormal(mean=numpy.log(mean),sigma=numpy.log(sigma),size=None)
        if age>=0 and age <= 100:
            break
    return age
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a suggestion as to how I can achieve the discarding the draw message?

Comment: look at my updated answer! just need to replace for with while :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def lognormal(mean,sigma):
    while True:
        age = np.random.lognormal(mean=np.log(mean),sigma=np.log(sigma),size=None)
        if age >= 0 and age <= 100:
            break
    return age
```

The accepted answer should not work. Maybe I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

The above answers only apply to a single value. If you want a vector of values within that range, you can either endlessly loop until you get a series of values that magically fit your range or you can replace the values outside of your range by re-drawing a sample from your base distribution (replace by exception).

```
i = 0
while True:
   # for first iteration, make an initial vector of random values
   if i == 0:
       V = np.round(np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1000),2)

   #Make binary vectors for those values that are out of range and in range
   V_outRange = (V > 100) + 0.
   V_good = (V < 100) + 0.

   #keep the values in range
   V_ok = np.multiply(V, V_good)

   #Resample values that are out of range
   V_next = np.round(np.multiply(V_outRange, np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1000)),2)

   #Re-combine previous in-range values with newly sampled values
   V = V_ok + V_next

   #check to see if all values are in range, if not re-loop
   if (np.count_nonzero(V > 100)) == 0:
       break

   i += 1
```